# Security: It is necessary to use JWT at .writeUTF() if I already tokenized the connection when stablishing it?

Tags: java, sockets, security

I have made a game in which a user, in order to get identified (login screen), makes a `socket.writeUTF(username, password);` to the server and gets back a token, which is signed and contains the userid.

With this token each user can make requests to the server such as move, jump...

But my question is: If i create a new Conection to the server (I'm using sockets) and i secure that connection with the user token as explained above, do I need to still sending and validating the token on every socket interaction?

There is some method a Hacker could send a query to the server using the socket of other user? Maybe sending a "jump" request to the socket in the port "123456"?

Or otherwise once the connection is made the socket on the server only listens to one exact IP and there is no way of useing that socket from other pcs so it wouldn't be necessary to send the token and validate it?

If someone knows how this works I may don't validate every single interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using secure sockets i.e. `SSLSockets`, your connection is not secure. There are plenty of attack vectors that are open with unsecured connections, and yes you can even spoof packets to the server pretending they're from a user.

So the simplest option would be to forget about your tokens and switch to `SSLSocket`. Remember that security is hard. Anything you make by yourself is going to be insecure unless you have a good understanding of information security.